# how to export all contact by API in hubspot to google spredsheet with app script

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script

**I try to export all contacts from hubspot to spreadsheet,
but I do not know how I can do it**

Comment: add more description and try to attach images or minimal reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

You would be wise to use the people api since the Contact API will begin to be shut down after June 15.  I've provided a function that I use.

You welcome to it.

Use what you wish.  Modify as needed.

```
function displayCurrentContacts() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Contacts');
  sh.clearContents();
  const vs = [['Name', 'Emails']];
  const resp = People.People.Connections.list('people/me', { personFields: "emailAddresses,names,organizations" });
  //Logger.log(resp);
  const data = JSON.parse(resp);
  let m = 0;
  let n = 0;
  data.connections.forEach((ob1, i) => {
    if (ob1.emailAddresses && ob1.emailAddresses.length > 0) {
      let emails = [... new Set(ob1.emailAddresses.map(ob2 => ob2.value))];//used set to insure I get unique list
      //let emails = ob1.emailAddresses.map(ob2 => ob2.value);
      let name;
      m += emails.length;
      if (ob1.names && ob1.organizations) {
        name = ob1.names[0].displayName + '\n' + ob1.organizations[0].name;
        ++n;
      } else if (ob1.names) {
        name = ob1.names[0].displayName;
        ++n;
      } else if (ob1.organizations) {
        name = ob1.organizations[0].name;
        ++n;
      }
      vs.push([name, emails.sort().join('\n')])
    }
  });
  vs.push([n, m])
  sh.getRange(1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs)
  sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 2, sh.getLastColumn()).sort({ column: 1, sortAscending: true });
}
```